# Touch events in a subview of a UITableViewCell of a static UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitouch, uicontrol

I have a custom switch

`UICustomSwtich`: `UISlider`

downloaded from [here](http://catamount.com/forums/download/file.php?id=102)

**How it works**

`UICustomSwitch` overwrite this touch events to work as it have to work:

```
- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

**Good tests**

`UICustomSwitch` works perfectly in any `UIView`, even a `UIScrollView`. The three touches events are called properly when it have to be called.

**Bad works**

Here's my problem. I have a static `UITableView` designed from StoryBoard with this hierarchy:

`UITableView`> `UITableViewCell`> `UIView` > `UICustomSwitch`

In this scenario:

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event`

This function is called properlly

`- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event`

`- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

When I move the thumb less than the length of the bar, the thumb remains at the same point I left it (the problem).

When I move the thumb to left and right (rises the end of the bar) the two methods are called (very strange behavior, isn't it?).

I looked for the answer finding similar problems with different solutions, but any good for my problem.

Why touch events sometimes reaches my `UICustomSwitch` and sometimes not? And why the events of ended and trackingWithTouch but not the began?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obtained a solution implementing all (less one commented) touch and track events:

```
#pragma - touches

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    LOG(@"touches began");

    m_touchedSelf = NO;
    on = !on;
}

//- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
//{
//    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
//    
//    LOG(@"touches moved");
//    
//}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    LOG(@"touches ended");

    if (!m_touchedSelf)
    {
        [self setOn:on animated:YES];
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}


- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];

    LOG(@"touches cancelled");

    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    if (location.x > self.frame.size.width/2) {
        [self setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }else{
        [self setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

}

#pragma - trackings

- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [super endTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];

    LOG(@"endTrackingWithTouch");

    m_touchedSelf = YES;

    if (self.value > 0.5) {
        [self setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }else{
        [self setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void) cancelTrackingWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    LOG(@"cancelTrackingWithEvent");

    m_touchedSelf = YES;

    if (self.value > 0.5) {
        [self setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }else{
        [self setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

When the control  is out of a table works with normal methods. When is inside a table, sometimes exit by cancelled methods and sometimes by ended methods. In any case, I obtained the correct behavior.

But there is a question unresolved.. Why `UITableView` or `UITableViewCell` cancell `UITouch` events of `UICustomSwitch`?